# c# change email encoding from utf-8 to iso-0-8859-1

Tags: c#, email, encoding, character-encoding

I send emails using the `System.Net.Mail`. Up till now i have set the mail encoding to utf-8, but now i have to send using ISO-8859-1 encoding. I understand, how I can change the encoding, can I safely change the encoding? What problems could I face changing this?

```
var email = new MailMessage(from, to)
{
    Subject = formManager.ReplaceValuesInString(alert.EmailSubject, replaceValues),
    IsBodyHtml = (alert.EmailMode == 2),
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I'd expect you to face is that while UTF-8 covers the whole of Unicode, ISO-8859-1 doesn't - it only has U+0000 to U+00FF (not even that, actually - there's a "hole" in ISO-8859-1 between U+0080 and U+009F). So if you try to send a text with characters not in ISO-8859-1, that text won't come through.

Answer (score 0):

***It depends on who is writing the email.***

If emails are all system generated (by you) just make sure no part of e-mails (if pulling something from dbase, web services...) contains inconsistent characters.
but if you are relaying on user input as whole/part of the email message, it's not so easy.

**Conclusion:** If the emails are system generated, it's safe to send them in any encoding as long as you take control over how the content is generated. If you don't have control, use a compatible encoding which covers every possible character may be needed to be stored by it.

**Notice:** Unless we are talking about a huge large of data storage, it is not recommended using other encodings rather than utf-8 for storing user-inputs. Also wasted space by using utf-8 encoding on dbase or file system can be saved by built-in compression methods of underlying systems (fs, dbase) and leave it to them.

Comment: The emails depends on data not controled by me. And the code is part of a CMS used by many clients. What i did was simply add a dropdownlist with different encodings so that it is posible to change for each email template.

Comment: I don't understand why you may need such an option when there's a all-in-one solution out there (utf-8). It doesn't worth.